# Click 2 Call script in a jpeg

Tags: javascript, php, function, jpeg

I do facebook mobile advertising and when a mobile user clicks my ad (JPEG) it takes them to a url where I have a mobile form with a click to call button  http://www.eduloannetwork.com/mobile. Making a 2 step process. I am looking for someone who can code the click to call function in to the JPEG making it a 1 step process.

Is this possible?

Comment: Show us your code (paste it into your question) and then explain what you want different.  Questions with your code in them usually get answers a lot better than questions that are just words.  Your code is sooooo much more descriptive of what you're trying to do.  Conceptually you just take the code in your click handler and move it to the page initialization so it runs when the page loads.

Comment: CAn you view the source of the click2call button @ www.eduloannetwork.com/mobile   ? and tell me?

Comment: Im looking to pay someone to do this...

Comment: This is a volunteer site, not the right place to solicit paid solutions.

Comment: <strong><span style="color: #0055a6;">Call for FREE eligibility check!!!</span></strong></p>
<p><a href="images/banner1.jpg"><img class="size-full wp-image-20 aligncenter" alt="banner1" src="images/banner1.jpg" width="320" height="168" /></a></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><div class="ezmbphoneimg"> <a class="phonebtnimg" href="tel:18557302071"><img src="images/callus.png" alt="Tap to Call" border="0"></a></div><div class="clear"></div></p>

Comment: I want to know if I can attatch this command to a JPEG

Comment: WHere would be a good place to get someone hired to do this?

Comment: Please do not put multiline HTML or javascript into comments.  It is not readable at all.  If you need to communicate multiple HTML or javascript, use the Edit button to add it to your question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the landing page you showed us, all the button on your landing page is doing is this:

```
<a class="phonebtnimg" href="tel:18557302071">
    <img src="images/callus.png" alt="Tap to Call" border="0">
</a>
```

If that's what you want to happen on the first click, then just change the link for the first page to have `href="tel:18557302071"` instead of a link to your page.

The phone would obviously have to process this URL appropriately, but apparently you think your 2nd page is already doing that for you so, if it is, then you can just move the same link from the 2nd page to the first page and skip the intermediate page entirely.